# Java plugin replacement for digital signatures

Tags: java, web, browser, plugins, digital-signature

We have a custom Java applet that performs certain tasks, like loading a PDF from local filesystem, signing it with certificates from system KeyStore/smart card etc. Such actions are not possible in regular HTML/JavaScript. Now that Java is being deprecated across browsers, we are looking for possibilities to replace the applet functionality.

There is this [Web Cryptography API](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/), but unfortunately the spec does not cover using system keystore. There is another spec for this, [WebCrypto Key Discovery](https://www.w3.org/TR/webcrypto-key-discovery/), but I don't think it is currently supported by any browser.

Mozilla had an [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/JavaScript_crypto) that might be exactly what we need, but unfortunately it is deprecated now.

So it looks like our only options are:

- Write a custom desktop GUI app
- Write a custom browser plugin

Or is there some better solution? What do you suggest? I don't care if the solution would be only for Internet Explorer since most of our users use.

Comment: If you really can focus on MSIE only then custom ActiveX is IMO the best choice.

Comment: @Martin S Did you implement any solution? I have the same problem and will be thankful if you help me

Comment: @BzH unfortunately no, still using a Java applet

Comment: Working solution using Signer.Digital Browser Extension is given in SO Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55676351/9659885

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to Java restrictions on browsers is not possible in general to use the OS native Key Store. You still can use Java in old versions of IE and Firefox, but Oracle has announced that will discontinue JRE plugin for browser, and Firefox decided to drop java support in 2017, so it is not recommended

**Write a browser plugin is not possible** because browsers do not allow access to several OS functions. In particular Chrome plugin API only allow access to user certificates in Chrome OS, not in Windows or Linux. For Edge, I think the plugin interface is not available yet.

There are some alternatives

- Use **WebCryptographyApi** to load a software certificate. See [How to load a PKCS#12 Digital Certificate with Javascript WebCrypto API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018233/how-to-load-a-pkcs12-digital-certificate-with-javascript-webcrypto-api)
- Use **chrome messaging api** (Estonian solution). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29806091/6371459
- Use a **local application connected through javascript** (Spanish solution) See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38658414/6371459

I personally have tested the first and the last options. For Estonian solution, I suggest to contact with the team. I think the currently support only some smartcards