# What is best alternative to Java applets for performing Digital Signatures

Tags: angularjs, vue.js, applet, digital-signature, jnlp

We were using java applets to digitally sign the document. As we know that java applets has been deprecated in almost all the browsers we have migrated to Jnlp.

Now with jnlp we are facing multiple downloads issue(Each time user has to download the jnlp file), since our web application contains multiple file uploads, each time downloading is not a good way.

Can anyone suggest a good way to implement digital signatures in AngularJs or VueJs technologies.

Thank you.

Comment: Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46194323/6371459

Comment: Ok thanks.i will check..

Comment: If you are looking free ready Browser extension, [Signer.Digital Chrome Extension](https://signer.digital/SignerDigitalBrowserExtensions) is the one provided by my company.